# Dereference operator for custom iterator in custom doubly linked list, binary operator not found

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, doubly-linked-list

I am implementing a generic doubly linked list container with a nested custom iterator in the container class. My problem is that when compiling I get:

> Error C2678   binary '*': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const List::ListIter' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

This error points to when trying to dereference a iterator on line 246 for example. The `operator*` for the iterator is implemented in the iterator class but the compiler does not seem to be able to find the overload.

Everything else seems to compile just fine when buildning

```
using std::cout;
template<class T> class List {
template<class T>
class Node;


public:
template <class T>
class Link {
public:
    friend class List<T>;
    Link* _next, *_prev;
    Link(Link *n, Link *p) : _next(n), _prev(p) {}
    Node<T>* Next() { return static_cast<Node<T>*>(_next); }
    Node<T>* Prev() { return static_cast<Node<T>*>(_next); }


};

template<class T>
class Node :public Link<T> {


public:
    friend class List<T>;
    Node(const T& data = NULL, Link<T> *n = NULL, Link<T> *p = NULL) :_data(data), Link<T>(n, p) {}
    T _data;
};


public:
template<class T> class ListIter {
public:
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef std::bidirectional_iterator_tag iterator_category;//behvöber fixas
    ListIter(Node<T>* p) {
        _ptr = p;
    }

    ListIter() {
        _ptr = nullptr;
    }

    ListIter(const ListIter& other) {
        _ptr = other._ptr;
    }

    ListIter& operator=(const ListIter& other) {
        if (_ptr == other._ptr) {
            return *this;
        }
        else {
            _ptr = other._ptr;
            return *this;
        }
    }

    T & operator*() {
        return _ptr->_data;
    }

    T* operator->() {
        return &_ptr->_data;
    }

    ListIter& operator++() {
        _ptr = static_cast<Node<T>*>(_ptr->_next);
        return *this;
    }

    ListIter& operator--() {
        _ptr = static_cast<Node<T>*>(_ptr->Prev());
        return *this;
    }

    ListIter operator++(int) {
        ListIter temp(*this);
        _ptr = static_cast<Node<T>*>(_ptr->_next);
        return temp;
    }

    ListIter operator--(int) {
        ListIter temp(*this);
        _ptr = static_cast<Node<T>*>(_ptr->Prev());
        return temp;
    }
private:
    Node<T>* _ptr;
};
using iterator = ListIter<T>;

~List() {

    int counter = 0;
    Link<T> *curr = _head;
    while (curr != nullptr)
    {
        Link<T> *remove = curr;
        curr = curr->_next;
        delete remove;
        counter++;
    }

    cout << "removed" << counter << std::endl;
}


List() :_head(nullptr) {};

List(const List& other) {

    if (other._head == nullptr) {
        _head = nullptr;
    }
    _head = new Node<T>(other._head->_data);
    Node<T> *tempOther = _head->Next();
    while (tempOther != other._head) {
        push_back(tempOther->_data);
        tempOther = tempOther->Next();
    }
}


List(List&& other) {
    _head = other._head;
    other._head = nullptr;
}

List(const char* other) {
    int i = 0;
    while (other[i] != '\0') {
        push_front(other[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

List& operator=(const List* other) {
    if (*this == *other) {
        return *this;
    }
    else {
        if (other->_head != NULL) {
            Link<T> *curr = _head;
            while (curr != nullptr)
            {
                Link<T> *remove = curr;
                curr = curr->_next;
                delete remove;
            }
            _head = new Node<T>(other->_head->_data);
            if (other->_head->Prev() != NULL) {
                Node<T> *prev = other->_head->Prev();
                while (prev != NULL) {
                    push_back(prev->_data);
                    prev = prev->Prev();
                }
            }
            other->~List();
        }
        else {
            throw std::exception("list empty");
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

List& operator=(List&& other) {
    while (_head->_next != _head)
    {
        Link<T> *remove = _head->_next;
        _head->_next = remove->_next;
        delete remove;
    }
    delete _head;
    _head = other._head;
    return *this;
}

T& front() {
    if (_head->_next != NULL) {
        return _head->Next()->_data;
    }
    else {
        throw std::exception("list is empty");
    }
}
T& back() {
    if (!empty()) {
        Node<T> *last = _head->Prev();

        return last->_data;
    }
    else {
        throw std::exception("list is empty");
    }
}

iterator begin() const {
    return ListIter<T>(_head);
}
iterator end() const {
    return ListIter<T>(_head->Prev());
}
bool empty() const noexcept {
    if (_head == NULL) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
size_t size() const noexcept {
    size_t counter = 0;
    if (empty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (_head->Next() == _head->Prev()) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        Link<T> *last = _head->_next;
        while (last != _head) {
            last = last->_next;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

iterator insert(const iterator& pos, const T& value) {
    if (empty()) {
        throw std::exception("list empty");
    }
    else {
        Node<T> prev = *pos->Prev();
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(value, *pos, prev);
        prev->_next = newNode;
        *pos->_prev = newNode;
    }
}
ListIter erase(const iterator& pos) {
    Link<T> next = (*pos)->_next;
    Link<T> prev = (*pos)->_prev;
    next._prev = prev;
    prev._next = next;
    delete *pos;
}

void push_front(const T& value) {
    if (empty()) {
        _head = new Node<T>(value);
    }
    else if (size() == 1) {
        Node<T> *newHead = new Node<T>(value, _head, _head);
        _head->_next = newHead;
        _head->_prev = newHead;
        _head = newHead;
    }
    else {
        Node<T> *newhead = new Node<T>(value, _head, _head->Prev());
        _head = newhead;
    }
}

void push_back(const T& value) {
    if (empty()) {
        _head = new Node<T>(value);
    }
    else if (size() == 1) {
        Node<T> *last = new Node<T>(value, _head, _head);
        _head->_next = last;
        _head->_prev = last;
    }
    else {
        Link<T> *last = _head->Prev();
        Node<T> *newLast = new Node<T>(value, _head, last);
        last->_next = newLast;
    }
}

void pop_back() {
    if (empty()) {
        throw std::exception("list is empty");
    }
    else {
        Link<T> *last = _head->Prev();
        Link<T> *beforeLast = last->Prev();
        beforeLast->_next = _head;
        delete last;
    }
}


void pop_front() {
    if (empty()) {
        throw std::exception("list is empty");
    }
    else {
        Link<T> *newFront = _head->Next();
        Link<T> *temp = _head->Prev();
        temp->_next = newFront;
        delete _head;
        _head = static_cast<Node<T>*>(newFront);
    }
}



friend bool operator==(const List& lhs, const List& rhs) {
    bool result = true;
    if (lhs.size() == rhs.size()) {
        if (!lhs.empty()) {
            Node<T> *lhsNode = lhs._head;
            Node<T> *rhsNode = rhs._head;
            while (lhsNode->_next != NULL && rhsNode->Next() != NULL) {
                if (lhsNode->_data != rhsNode->_data) {
                    result = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            throw std::exception("list empty");
        }


    }
    else {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& cout, const List& other);

void Check() const {
    /*assert(Invariant());*/
}

template< class T>
void swap(List<T>& lhs, List<T>& rhs) {
    Node<T> temp = rhs._head;
    rhs._head = lhs._head;
    lhs._head = temp;
}
private:
Node<T> *_head;

};
```

I just need to access the value that the dereferenced iterator is supposed to give.

Comment: Aside: Why split `Link` and `Node` when `Next` and `Prev` return `Node *`?

Comment: In the assignment is says that we are supposed to split them to be able to have insert and erase inside the link class. That way all insert functions inside the list class could call the insert inside link. I didn't really understand how that was going to make things easier so i just started coding it like this in the hope that I would either understand more later or that the teacher would accept it this way.

Comment: Either you have a weird C++ teacher, or misunderstood. (The first is unfortunately too common to rule out). It makes sense to split `List`, `ListIter` and `Node`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `insert` and `erase` you have `const iterator& pos`.  Since you pass by reference to a constant the iterator is `const`.  Your `operator*` is not marked as `const` so you cannot use it on a constant object. You either need to provide a `const` overload or drop the `const` from the function parameter.